# How to embed a file in an excel spreadsheet in a compact manor

Tags: microsoft-excel

Wanted:

1. Embed the file in the spreadsheet (no links to external files)
2. No image or a text only image. When you embed a file w/ `Insert > Object > Create from File`, it inserts it w/ a large image.

Tried:
`Insert > Object > Create from File` - Image too large and Display as Icon checkbox, doesn't do anything useful.
Linking to the external file - Looks good, but requires the file to be in a specific location relative to your file.

**UPDATE**
Is there perhaps a way to name the embeded object, that create a hyperlink to it?

Comment: What version of Excel are you using, and what type of file are you trying to embed? I tried inserting a file and checking the Display as Icon box in both Excel 2010 and Excel 2016, and both just displayed an icon with a caption.

Comment: Outlook 2013. I get the same thing. I don't want the Icon. It's too bulky.